# MyISAM to InnoDB conversion failed but my disk space increased

Tags: mysql, database

My database table is 32 GB and I tried to convert the database engine from MyISAM to InnoDB and then I waited a long time but its failed due to the disk being full.

I am checking the table is still MyISAM but my disk space is still almost full.

Can someone help in figuring out where I can find where those extra GBs are?

There's almost 30 GB of space I am not able to find on the server.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use free tool WinDirStats to find large files on disk

Comment: @Sonikas its on aws server. can you tell me any command or something on that.

Comment: Also i checked my database become double size.

Comment: Do you have remote desktop access or just command line? Is this server is windows based or linux?

Comment: @Sonikas linux based only command line